# Add more values to the bearer token json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, owin, bearer-token

I want to return the user name after they logged in successfully to display on the upper right corner on my web app. I want to send it with the json that bearer the token returns. To generate the token authentication I'm using ASP.NET web API and Owin middlehawe.

```
{   
  "access_token": "blah",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 599
}
```

I want the return to be like this

```
{   
  "access_token": "blah",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 599,
  "displayusername":"Hi Mundo"
}
```

I have tried claims but those are not giving the result I want.

I have tried to use AuthenticationProperties but doesn't work

```
 public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
        if (validation works)
        {
           // add claims

            var moreInfo = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "username", "Don"}, { "Department","MIS"} });

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, moreInfo);
            context.Validated(ticket);
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
        }
    }
```

How do I add more values to the json that the owin bearer token returns?.

Comment: I really don't understand your question. In the first part of your post you say, "return the user name after they logged in successfully" but then later you say "because I'm not authorizing my user." Those statements appear contradictory. Regardless, claims are the best way to pass information about the user.

Answer (score 6):

Override `TokenEndpointResponse` on same class you are checking for validity and return additional field as shown in sample below

```
public override Task TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context)
{
    string thisIsTheToken = context.AccessToken;
    //add user Id and status as additional response parameter
    context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add("displayusername", "Hi Mundo");
    context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add("Status", "1");     
    return base.TokenEndpointResponse(context);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simple do it by Add new item to `moreInfo.Dictionary` :

```
moreInfo.Dictionary.Add("username", user.UserName);
moreInfo.Dictionary.Add("Department","MIS");
```

Answer (score 0):

in ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs file add your properties in below method :

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
            {
              
                AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName,user.FirstName,user.LastName);
              
            }




public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName,string FirstName,string LastName)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "userName", userName },
                { "FirstName", FirstName },
                { "LastName", LastName },
            };
            return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
        }
```